# Phone number validation regex with custom constraints

Tags: javascript, regex

I should validate a phone number. My constraints are like this.

1. Phone numbers should not contain alphabets(silly though to mention ;) )
2. Phone number should have minimum 10 characters and maximum 17 characters.
3. phone number should accept "-" , ".", "+".(not mandatory)
4. "-" or "." if present, should not be in starting of number or ending of number.
5. Only one "+" is allowed and that too in the starting of the number
6. Phone number should not be valid if all the characters entered are "-" or "."

So far i am using the following expression.

```
var phoneExpression = /^(?=.*[0-9])([0-9\.\-\+\ \(\)\/]+)*$/;
```

though this is not meeting all my constraints. Please provide me a good `regular expression`.

Comment: *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.* - [JWZ](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski)

Comment: I didn't get you @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Will `0--------0` be considered a valid phone # (it meets all the requirement in your question)?

Comment: you may be require a couple of regex, a single regex would be quite complex for the same. advisable solution is to do this validation in code itself.

Comment: Your requirements also say nothing about characters other than digits and those in the class of [-+.]   But your regex also appears to include spaces and parentheses. Please clarify.  What do you really want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should meet all the constraints except for 10 characters and maximum 17 characters because it will not count the + sing if present. If you need that you should duplicate the regex with an alternation `|`

```
^\+?[0-9][0-9.-]{8,15}[0-9]$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cH1kH9/1)

Answer (score 1):

This meets all your written constraints, counting the + as a character if present:

```
(?=^.{10,17}$)\+?\d[\d.-]+\d$
```

If you want to add Parentheses and or spaces, merely put them inside the character class.
I suspect this is not adequate as your description will accept constructs that are clearly not phone numbers.